Gudhi python library did not show the output for dimension 1
The following code is for "Homology Groups". I used library for implementation purpose.
import gudhi

# Create a simplicial complex
simplex_tree = gudhi.SimplexTree()
simplex_tree.insert([1, 2, 3])
simplex_tree.insert([2, 3, 4])
simplex_tree.insert([3, 4, 5])

# Compute homology
homology = simplex_tree.persistence()

print("Homology groups:")
for interval in homology:
    dim, (birth, death) = interval
    print(f"Dimension {dim}: birth = {birth}, death = {death}")

The output I get
Homology groups:
Dimension 0: birth = 0.0, death = inf

Why I did not get the output for Dimension 1?

The reason is:
As defined in the code, there are no non-trivial 1-dimensional loops.
if there is no 1-d features that presist by homology
e.g.
a loop like 1>2>3>1 exists but it is filled by triangle so it does not contribute to the first homology group H1
I hope you will get the point, otherwise you can ask for further clarification and I will further explain
try these lines in your code as well to loop and print the H1 I hope it will work for you :)
print("Homology groups:")
for interval in 
 simplex_tree.persistence_intervals_in_dimension(0):
 print(f"Dimension 0: birth = {interval[0]}, death = 
 {interval[1]}")

for interval in 
 simplex_tree.persistence_intervals_in_dimension(1):
 print(f"Dimension 1: birth = {interval[0]}, death = 
 {interval[1]}")


Still the output is same "Homology groups:
Dimension 0: birth = 0.0, death = inf", Can you give an example code where dimension1 will also show?

Can you please double check and confirm that your gudhi package is installed successfully and it's imported in the right way , sometimes some dependencies may create problems

Can you try this with 1 D cycle
import gudhi
# Create a simplicial complex with a 1D cycle
simplex_tree = gudhi.SimplexTree()
simplex_tree.insert([1, 2])
simplex_tree.insert([2, 3])
simplex_tree.insert([3, 4])
simplex_tree.insert([4, 1])  
# Forms a 1D loop

# Compute homology
homology = simplex_tree.persistence()

print("Homology groups:")
for interval in homology:
dim, (birth, death) = interval
print(f"Dimension {dim}: birth = {birth}, death = {death}")

Homology groups:
Dimension 0: birth = 0.0, death = inf
Dimension 1: birth = 0.0, death = inf

Now its working for myself as I just change in your code and limited the dim to 1d Create a simplicial complex with a 1D cycle
